# How to generate movie of the simulation done in LAMMPS?

Tags: simulation, molecular-dynamics

I simulated nanowire deformation using LAMMPS and visualized it using VMD in Centos 6.5. But I'm not able to generate .jpg image file or the simulation movie. How can I proceed??

Comment: Welcome on Computational Science. This question appears to be off topic, since is related to a particular software.

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little detail as to 'not able' means. I suppose you have error in your lammps output.

Check the page http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/dump_image.html that gives instructions. Most importantly, check that you compiled lammps with the appropriate options ( -DLAMMPS_JPEG being the most obvious )